# Ruby on Rails Error on Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, windows-10, chown

How can I solve this problem? please, help.
I am using windows 10 and I am trying to run this already existing RoR project.I am very newbie to these projects. Here an error with stack:

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.6/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- 2.2/http11 (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:17:in`rescue in '
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in`require'
        from C:/bottomup_source/bottomup_source/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in`require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in`tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in`require'
        from script/rails:6:in `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i m using ruby on rails from last one year , i would recommend you to use linux or ubuntu for ruby on rails as most of the tools are not compatible with  windows for development, but still if you want to use on windows os the follow this [ruby on rails on window](http://railsinstaller.org/en) hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I have to use it on windows 10 .this guide isn't helping me.Thanks.